# Install Marklogic centos virtualbox vm

Tags: linux, installation, centos6, marklogic

I recently set up a CentOS 6.4 basic LAMP server (no GUI) in a pre-built Virtualbox image, and then followed the installation guide/steps for MarkLogic.

When I attempt install with `rpm -i /tmp/MarkLogic-8.0-1.x86_64.rpm`, MarkLogic states that it cannot find libc.so.6, however when I run the command `whereis libc.so.6`, the shell responds with `/lib64/libc.so.6`
I would make a symbolic link I suppose, but I'm not sure where MarkLogic is expecting that file to be.

Does anyone have experience installing MarkLogic on Centos6 and how to verify the install is working properly?  While ML gave some good instructions, I am very new to CentOS and Redhat, in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running the following yum command before installing MarkLogic should be sufficient normally:

```
yum -y install glibc.i686 gdb.x86_64 redhat-lsb.x86_64
```

You can also look at this and related scripts for more inspiration:

https://github.com/grtjn/mlvagrant/blob/master/opt/mlvagrant/install-ml-centos.sh#L17

HTH!

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I first had to disable the PackageKit as that was causing yum lock issues, but otherwise -- I ran yum clean metadata, then yum clean all. I then did the yum install as you suggested, and the MarkLogic server installed quickly, easily, and without pain. Thank you again.

Comment: The link above is nolonger valid i got 404 page not found.  Can you please tell me the correct link.. Thanks

Comment: my bad, I moved the files from opt/vagrant/ to opt/mlvagrant/ to prevent conflicts with Vagrant installation files. I fixed the link..