# glibc 2.11 error on Marklogic 8.0 installation on CentOS 6.6

Tags: centos, glibc, marklogic

When I try to install Marklogic 8.0 (MarkLogic-8.0-2.x86_64.rpm) on CentOS6.6 it fails with following error:

> error: Failed dependencies:
>           `libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.11) is needed by MarkLogic-8.0-2.x86_64`

I checked installed package of `glibc` and found that GLIB_2.12 is installed.
I tried erasing `GLIBC_2.12`, but Cent OS doesn't allow because it has dependencies.

I would appreciate if somebody help me how to install Marklogic 8.0 on CentOS6.6 keeping glibc 2.12 or how to downgrade glib version on CentOs

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested myself with CentOS 6.6, but am running CentOS 6.5 a lot. Did you try running this before the RPM?

```
yum -y install glibc.i686 gdb.x86_64 redhat-lsb.x86_64
```

See also [Install Marklogic centos virtualbox vm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28703042/install-marklogic-centos-virtualbox-vm/28703744#28703744)

HTH!

Comment: You might be interested by this blog post as well: http://h2oconsulting.be/blog/virtual-box-marklogic.

Comment: Thanks. Works fine with above installation

Answer (score 2):

To add to this: you're seeing this message when you attempt to install because a dependent library is unavailable; in the case of this particular message, if you run this beforehand:

```
yum install glibc.i686
```

You should get past that particular issue.