# MarkLogic install error on centos 7.2

Tags: installation, marklogic

I am trying to install MarkLogic-RHEL6-8.0-5.x86_64.rpm on CENTos7 - and getting this error:

```
[root@localhost marklogic]# rpm -i MarkLogic-RHEL6-8.0-5.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
    libsasl2.so.2()(64bit) is needed by MarkLogic-8.0-5.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.11) is needed by MarkLogic-8.0-5.x86_64
```

Could not find any way to resolve this using yum or any other way.

OS version is:

```
[root@localhost marklogic]# cat /etc/*elease
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="centos.org/";
BUG_REPORT_URL="bugs.centos.org/";
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
```

Thanks in advance - help would be appreciated.

Comment: correction - version is 7.2:

Comment: [root@localhost marklogic]# cat /etc/*elease
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core) 
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"

CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core) 
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28703042/install-marklogic-centos-virtualbox-vm

Comment: You may follow stackoverflow link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28703042/install-marklogic-centos-virtualbox-vm

Answer (score 3):

You used the installer for Red Hat 6 / CentOS 6. Try the one for `Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Version 7`: http://developer.marklogic.com/products

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

RHEL 7  uses the newer **libsasl2.so.3**. However, MarkLogic requires **libsasl2.so.2**. Unfortunately there is no symlink to libsasl2.so.2 by default.

For MarkLogic 8 on RHEL 7x and CentOS 7x, you need to manually create a symbolic link in **/usr/lib64**

```
/usr/lib64/libsasl2.so.2 --> /usr/lib64/[your sasl version - mine is libsasl2.so.3.0.0]
```

Comment: I was using this in mlvagrant `ln -s /lib64/libsasl2.so.3 /lib64/libsasl2.so.2`, but you don't need that when using the RHEL7 rpm..

Comment: thanks both for answers - I took this one: ]# rpm -i MarkLogic-RHEL7-8.0-5.x86_64.rpm   - and only had to install yum install glibc.i686 - and that did it. MarkLogis started now and console working fine.